# Spring Security Ajax login to verify, Is user logged in via Ajax call

Tags: ajax, grails, spring-security

I am using

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
```

and

```
compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2"
```

for Spring Security login. I am able to successfully logged in via normally (without Ajax call).

But when I go to call via Ajax I set `ajax= true` its working fine. But problem is that In both case it's going to `HomeController` and we recognized ROLE of user and redirect on different url based on ROLE.

Is there any solution to verify is user logged in via Ajax or normal
or
How to get `ajax= true` variable in `HomeController` ?

Comment: I cant get what you mean, but to check if the request is ajax, I think you can use request.isAjax() method.

Comment: hi is used request.isXHR() to shortout the problem can you tell what is the use of it

Comment: It tells you whether the request is coming from ajax or normal http request.